# VBA Find & Replace but excluding words before the instance

Tags: vba, ms-word, replace

Lets say I want to use VBA Word to find/replace.  I want to find replace the word "page" with "page (title needs bolded" but I ONLY want to do this if the preceding word(s) are not "continued on next"

I tried to find the word and then used key commands to ctrl+shift+left arrow and IF those = "continued on next" do nothing, else replace the "page" with the "page (title needs bolded).

```
   Sub SpellingSuggestionPage()

Dim wrd As Range
Dim srchText As String, avdText As String, replWord As String
Dim ar() As String
Dim ignoreWord As Boolean

srchText = "page"
avdText = "next"
replWord = "page (title needs bolded)"

ar = Split(avdText, " ")

For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words

    ignoreWord = False

    If wrd = srchText Then

        If wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text = avdText Or wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Bold Then
              ignoreWord = True
        End If

        If ignoreWord = False Then
            wrd.Text = replWord
        End If

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @user1243498: As mentioned by Brettdj, this question is a duplicate of the quesiton mentioned in the link. I was planning on answering there but realized that you had no answers in that link and you already have a response on this one. If you feel that both the threads are the same then you may close the other one :)

Comment: total newbie and not sure how to "close" the other one so i voted to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wrd As Range
    Dim srchText As String, avdText As String, replWord As String
    Dim ar() As String
    Dim ignoreWord As Boolean

    srchText = "page"
    avdText = "continued on next"
    replWord = "page (title needs bolded)"

    ar = Split(avdText, " ")

    For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
        ignoreWord = False

        If wrd = srchText Then
            If Trim(wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text) = Trim(ar(2)) Then
                If Trim(wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2).Text) = Trim(ar(1)) Then
                    If Trim(wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=3).Text) = Trim(ar(0)) Then
                        ignoreWord = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            If ignoreWord = False Then
                wrd.Text = replWord
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It only works on "continued on next page" text.  IE if I put "Continued on next page" and "continued on next page" it'll replace it on the first instance with the capital "C" and ignore the 2nd option like it's supposed to.  However if I have "right on this page" it will skip that as well and I need it to capture those.  It should only skip "page" if the preceding words = "continued on next page" and any/all other instances of page should be replaced as discussed.  **Not sure if this can be done but any way to do a seperate macro that can check if the preceding word is bolded and skip that too

Comment: This works, but it will not flag page in this example:  "This page is bad." OR in this example "This page doesn't need bolded."  However, it would work if there are three words in front of page like "Not on this page."  I'm not sure how to modify to account for that.  Also, can we add a seperate check in there to see if the previous word in front of page is bolded and if it is then to skip as that is what the macro is trying to tell the user, unless it says "continued on next page." :):)

Comment: Yes the above example is case sensitive and was specific to your question asked. If you don't want case sensitive check then change `Trim(wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text)` to `UCASE(Trim(wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text))` and change `Trim(ar(2))` to `UCASE(Trim(ar(2)))`. Similarly do for others. If you have more or less than 3 words then adjust the nested `If` and `Endif` section.

Comment: OK I can manage that . . any tips on how to check if the trim = bolded?  I tried adding if .selection.font = bold and it says its an invalid ref

Comment: If you want to check if the previous word is bold then use this `If wrd.Previous(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Bold Then`

Comment: I updated my post above with the code I'm using and it's still not quite right.

Comment: Fixed it.  Thanks again Siddharth!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think this might do it:

```
If InStr(value, "page") > 0 And InStr(value, "continued on next") = 0 Then
    value = Replace(value, "page", "page (title needs bolded)")
End If
```

That says : if value contains "page" anywhere and it does not contain "continued on next" anywhere, then replace "page" with "page (title needs bolded)".

Comment: I set up a test and it's not doing the replace.  I set up a few "page" and "continued on next page" tests all in a single page doc and it didn't find the instances to change.  any other ideas mate?